# Cannot connect to MongoDB via NodeJS - No primary found in replica set error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am having difficulty connecting to MongoDB via NodeJS. The Mongo setup consists of a shared cluster.

The URL is below:

mongodb://dev.testserver.com:27017,dev.testserver.com:27018,dev.testserver.com:27019/ua?w=0&replicaSet=dev-testserver-com&readPreference=secondary&slaveOk=true

The code that I have is below:

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }

  db.close();
});
```

The error that I keep getting is "MongoError: no primary found in replicaset".

Can someone please help?

Comment: And of course you can connect to your RS (from command line) with 'mongo --host "dev-testserver-com/dev.testserver.com:27017,dev.testserver.com:27018,dev.testserver.com:27019" ua' -command?

Comment: @JJussi Thats not what I am looking for. I am looking to specifically connect using NodeJS.

Comment: I asked tuhat just to check tuhat your replucaset is actually working and there is no connection problem. So many times I have seen that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem in your server(s). You need to get on the server(s) and run [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) to find out the state of your replica set, and each server's logs to find out if and why one or more has stopped or become disconnected.

Comment: Are you sure? The connection is saying that there are no primaries in the replica set, but there's no indication of a problem on any of the servers?

Comment: None I am afraid.